# Who Was Gebansha Pir?

Tags: sufism

I would like to know who Gebansha Pir was.  I presume he must've had some major significance to Sufis, as I have seen many *[dargaah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dargah)* erected for him throughout Gujarat, but beyond that I know nothing.

I have been unable to find any information on him, neither details of his own life nor even why he is revered so.

So I pose the question thus: **Who exactly was Gebansha Pir?**

Any details on his life (and death) would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps 'honour' rather than 'worship' may be better in this context? We also have many Pirs in Bangladesh, the people honour them, and pray for their souls and guidance.

Comment: @MoziburUllah : True ,but do you know about Gebansha Pire ? am actually interested to know about him.anyways thanks...

Comment: I have edited the post for grammar and to make it clearer what you are asking.  Please review and ensure I have communicated your question properly.

Comment: If you have to ask something about Suffism, then plz do so by specifying that you require sufi view only, else it is nothing related to Islam, or **this question specifically might be opinion based too**

Answer (score -1):

I think "Geban" means to hide something.

A person or a soul who wants to help someone without letting know anybody thier name,means helping without letting anybody know who helped might be called "GebanshaPir" - a pir helps without saying who he is.